# How to turn on/off Bluetooth in Windows Phone 7 in my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth

I still have not figured out how to turn on and turn off Blurtooth can within my application. Or some information about Bluetooth at this time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for Bluetooth functionality.
Apparently it's not coming in the Mango update either.

Comment: Thanks Matt Lacey
so, unfortunately!
Right now I need to write an application related to bluetooth, had to wait only

Comment: If your app must use Bluetooth then you can't currently write it for WP7.

Comment: I want turn off and turn on bluetooth because we want to be able turn on and turn off bluetooth right in your application instead of the user to adjust the setting. What is not possible with Bluetooth in window phone 7 <br>Thanh you very much !</br>