# How to search for Bluetooth devices in Windows Phone 7 using Silverlight?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, bluetooth

How to search Bluetooth devices in Silverlight on Windows phone 7 programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for Bluetooth functionality.
Apparently it's not coming in the Mango update either.

See:

[How to turn on/off Bluetooth in Windows Phone 7 in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093710/how-to-turn-on-off-bluetooth-in-window-phone-7-in-my-app)